# Is there a method to verify the settings for maas? Juju is not able to work yet

Tags: server, juju, maas

**First, information about my setup:**

MAAS master controller setup on a Dell server with future access to 96 HP servers being prepared in the data center. Currently have 2 HP servers "available" in MAAS (1 deployed and 1 commissioned). Originally had second Dell server to be used for juju administration but unable to get this method to work, so trying to add second Dell server into MAAS for potential use.

**Some problems I am experiencing:**

Initial test of juju seemed to start working but unable to get "juju status" to work. Tried to "destroy environment" to start fresh.

After deleting environment in juju, unable to add a new environment, stating environment is already bootstrapped.

After restarting Dell server, so it could be picked up by MAAS, unable to get it to commission, error is "Failed to query node's BMC — Node could not be queried node-dfda46ce-769b-11e5-8693-0024e880b8dd (experienced-scent.local) connection timeout". Had to delete the node so it stopped trying to connect to it every 5 minutes.

Cannot log onto server that has been acquired. IP address is pingable but ssh command fails with public key error.

**What to provide for help:**

Looking for information that I need to provide to get support for this.

Urgency is high as 4 to 6 developers are waiting for systems to use.